# How to use error "the changes you requested to the table is not succesful ... duplicate data..." as a warning form?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am working with Access database. I know once a field is in primary key, we cant insert a same value in a column.

What do I want:

I would like to use another form as warning form (exp: messageBox.show(`this value exist in current table`) instead of ERROR form: `The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.`

Is there anyway to help me make this?

Comment: Just check that no duplicate value exists before saving. You don't specify *how* you try to store the data, but if you are using a form, just add code that checks for duplicates before saving

Comment: Thanks for your require. I did it and it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using access form you could use the OnError() event to trap the error and handle it the way you want.

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
Select Case DataErr
Case Is = 3022
    Err.Clear
    Response = acDataErrContinue
    ' The Code you like to use
   End Select
 Case Else
 'handle other Errors 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm afraid of I cant use this code because im working with WindowForm in C#.